# Adding opencv Contrib library to python

Tags: opencv3.0

I have successfully added the cv2 library in python but not able  to add the opencv Contrib library to python ? So give me some solution,by the way i am a windows user and i am using idle IDE for running python.

Comment: Can you share some  ode and an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Cv2 library with integrated opencv Contrib library is now available on this link for python 3.5 for windows OS users.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6/3.5 you could use *.whl (Python on Wheels) module [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv):

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

For Python 2.7 there is no opencv+contrib in one module, but you could separately install opencv module [from here at the end of the page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) and then add `opencv-contrib-python` module:

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Do not mix opencv+contrib `opencv-python (3.2.0+contrib)` and o`pencv-contrib-python (3.2.0.7)` modules, otherwise your "`import cv2`" stop to work till you delete `opencv-contrib-python` module.